# Using data in BufferedImage that is drawn by Graphics

Tags: java, image, graphics, bufferedimage

I have the method below:

```
private Graphics getBufferedImage(Image image) {
    // Create empty BufferedImage, sized to Image
    buffImage  = 
      new BufferedImage(
          image.getWidth(null), 
          image.getHeight(null), 
          BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw Image into BufferedImage
    Graphics wholeImage = buffImage.getGraphics();
    return wholeImage;
}
```

It takes an Image and tries to generate the BufferedImage with a Graphics object.

What can I do with this Graphics (or BufferedImage) to actually let me use it? I'm using GIF files.

Would it be easier to use a byte array to transfer Image data over?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `OutputStream` object using method `ImageIO.write(...)`. Now you can transfer it over the network or save to file or store to array or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Graphics.drawImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) to draw the original image in the new image. In fact you can use any operation that `Graphics` offers, as well as cast it to `Graphics2D` (because that's what it is) and use those operations too.